# How do I take the inner product of a subdifferential with a vector?

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

I'm reading [this pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0546.pdf) about an implementation of the PDHG algorithm for convex minimization. At the beginning of page 9, authors make an operation I can't not understand.

In short, this is what happens:

Let $K \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in \mathbb{R}^m$. $f^*$ and $g$ are convex functions, $\partial f^*$ and $\partial g$ are their respctive subdifferentials. I define the following:

$$u = \begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$M_k = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{\tau}I & -K^T \\
  -K & \frac{1}{\sigma}I
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$R(u) = \begin{bmatrix}
  \partial g(x) + K^Ty \\
  \partial f^*(y) -Kx
 \end{bmatrix}$$

For this question it is not important if $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are variable or constant.

The iterates of the PDHG algorithm satisfy (eq 35 in the paper):
$$0 \in R(u_{k+1}) + M_k(u_{k+1} - u_k) \tag{1}$$
The optimally condition is (eq 36 in the paper):
$$0 \in R(u^*) \tag{2}$$
Also $R$ is a monotone operator:
$$(u-\hat{u})^T(R(u) - R(\hat{u})) \geq 0, \forall u, \hat{u}$$
Subtracting equation 1 from 2 results:
$$M_k(u_{k+1} - u_k) \in R(u^*) - R(u_{k+1}) \tag{3}$$
Everything ok until next step: how to take the inner product of equation 3 with $(u^* - u_{k+1})$ to get:
$$(u^* - u_{k+1})^TM_k(u_{k+1} - u_k) \geq (u^* - u_{k+1})^T(R(u^*) - R(u_{k+1}))$$
I don't know how authors get this result. Is it calculated from the definition of subdiferential or its resolvent? How can I take the inner product with a set and get an inequality?

**Edit:**
The notation used by authors is pretty ugly. If I do:

Let $R$ be monotone and let $u\in R(x), v\in R(y) \Rightarrow u-v \in R(x) - R(y)$ then
$$(x-y)^T(u-v) \ge 0$$
I also have $M_k(u-v) \in R(x) - R(y)$

Let $m_k = M_k(u - v) \Rightarrow m_k \in R(x) - R(y) \Rightarrow (x - y)^Tm_k \geq 0$

And at the end I just replace $x = u^*, y = u^{k+1}$.

So the step
$$(u^* - u_{k+1})^TM_k(u_{k+1} - u_k) \geq (u^* - u_{k+1})^T(R(u^*) - R(u_{k+1}))$$
Is unnecessary, maybe incorrect, and confusing.

Thanks xel!

Comment: I would highly encourage you to use the notation I used in my answer, i.e.
$ (x-y)^T (u-v)$ for  $u\in R(x)$ and $v\in R(y)$ instead of $(x-y)^T(R(x)-R(y))$ as it is much cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the rest of the paper, but the way you (and they) present it is the following:
Let $R$ be monotone and let $u_0\in R(x), v_0\in R(y)$, then
$$
(x-y)^T(u_0-v_0) \ge (x-y)^T(u-v)
$$
for *all* $u\in R(x), v\in R(y)$, which is not true. 
However, the (relevant) conclusion 
$$
(u^*-u_{k+1})^T M_k (u_{k+1}-u_k) \ge 0
$$
is still true and follows simply from monotonicity.

So there are two possibilties; either the statement follows from some special property of the matrix $M_k$ or;
it was just a mistake that went unnoticed because the only relevant conclusion is still true (personally I believe the second option to be much more likely).